# Given a tensor [5,4,3,4], how to generate a constant tensor where each row has n ones and m zeros, n=5,4,3,4, and m=0,1,2,1.

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Given a tensor A: `[5,4,3,4]`, I want to create a tensor B:

`[[1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1,0],
  [1,1,1,0,0],
  [1,1,1,1,0]]`

Each row of B has n ones where n = 5,4,3,4 according to A. The remaining positions are filled with zeros.

Can I realize this in tensorflow, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [tf.sequence_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) for this.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([5,4,3,4], dtype=tf.int32)
max_len = tf.reduce_max(A)
B = tf.sequence_mask(A, max_len, dtype=tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(B))
```

Prints:

```py
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0]]
```